# PHP mail - from argument

Tags: php, security, email

I am new to php, today I learned to use php mail and I'm kinda confused. How come I can write something like:

```
mail("example@example.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n")
```

and then the reciever sees in the from field whatever I put in $from? I could write an address of any institution/company/etc there and the reciever would think that it's legit email.

Isn't that totally insecure? What's the catch?

Comment: Damn you robot-reviewers: how the hell did you accept adding the "phpmailer" tag??

Comment: @DamienPirsy I already rolled it back

Answer (score 1):

The from address is sent in the message in the message header.

A [SPF (Sender Policy Framework)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) on the sending domain can be used to verify that mail has come from its said source.

If received mail does not comply with the SPF appropriate action on the receivers mail server may be taken such as moving the message into the spam folder or rejecting it entirely.

Comment: Have you actually read the article you link to? SPF ad DKIM are commonly used to authenticate email. I've never seen a SRV record anywhere.

Comment: You are correct SPF not SRV, Edited